# Does Testflight migration to iTunes Connect retain the same application icon and data?

Tags: ios, core-data, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm wondering if TestFlight users will be able to retain their data (in Core Data and User Defaults) after I migrate my app to iTunes Connect TestFlight, or if their app will be totally reset?  (or if it will install to a different application icon)

Thanks

Comment: The only way an app could install "to a different icon" was if app bundle id was changed. As long as you use same bundle id, signing identity and entitlements (if any), no data should be lost.

Comment: That was what I figured, thanks for the info.  If you add it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it and it looks like NSUserDefaults and Core Data are retained no problem, with the same app name.  However, TestFlight did give me a warning that app data might be deleted, so there could be other circumstances where data gets erased.